# Why does Tensorflow 2.4.1 not find my GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm having trouble using my GPU with tensorflow.
I pip installed tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1
I also installed CUDA 11.2 and cudnn 11.2, following the procedure from: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#installwindows , also checking that all paths are fine and the libraries are at the correct place.

However, when  I run `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')` on my Jupyter Notebook, it doesn't find my GPU.

I also run `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()`, which is returning True.

So is the problem that my GPU isn't supporting the current version of CUDA or cudnn? My GPU is "NVIDIA GeForce 605"

Comment: Your (rather old) card is not [listed](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) as having Cuda support

Comment: The card has CUDA support, but it was deprecated a few years ago. More importantly this card has no and has never had support in Tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

`NVIDIA GeForce 605` card based on `Fermi 2.0` architecture and I can see only `Ampere`,`Turing`, `Volta`, `Pascal`, `Maxwell` and `Kepler` are supported for `CUDA 11.x`.

As per @talonmies, `GeForce 605` card never had supported for Tensorflow.

You can refer [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) for NVIDIA GPU cards with CUDA architectures are supported for Tensorflow.

For GPUs with unsupported CUDA architectures to use different versions of the NVIDIA libraries, you can refer [Linux build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) guide.

Finally, you can also refer tested built configurations for [Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) and [linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).